# Exporting online Esri basemap layers to raster using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, imagery, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have been working on polygonizing the vegetation areas in some counties from imagery. When I have the mosaic raster locally I can easily get the polygons using [Image Classification Toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Image_Classification_toolbar/00nv00000008000000/). But when it comes to using online Esri imagery I don't know what to do. I was wondering if someone could suggest me a way to help in saving these basemap as raster locally. When I right lick on the layer it doesn't give me the Export option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ArcMap 10.2, I just tested drawing imagery from Add Basemap and then using File | Export Map to create a raster (in my case `*.jpg`) file, and this worked fine.